# Javascript array with multiple objects - send to GTM - Google data layer

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have multiple products on a page each with several infos and i need to send them to google data layer on page load within an array of objects.
My script the way it is is sending one array with a object with all fields on it, what i need is to have that same array with an object per product. Here's my code and hope someone can help me. Thanks

```js
$(function () {

        var Container = (".product");

        var itemName = $($(Container)).find(".item-name").text();

        var itemId = $($(Container)).find(".item-id").text();

        var itemPrice = $($(Container)).find(".item-price").text();

        var itemBrand = $($(Container)).find(".item-brand").text();

        var itemCategory = $($(Container)).find(".item-category").text();

        window.dataLayer.push({
            event: 'Ecommerce - Item List Views',
            event_name: 'view_item_list',
            view_item_list: {
                items: [{
                    item_name: itemName,
                    item_id: itemId, 
                    price: itemPrice, 
                    item_brand: itemBrand,
                    item_category: itemCategory, 
                }]
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="item-name">
            <h1>Nike blue shoes</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item-id">
            SKU-3456
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">
            €22.00
        </div>
        <div class="item-brand">
            Nike
        </div>
        <div class="item-category">
            Shoes
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="item-name">
            <h1>Adidas red shoes</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item-id">
            SKU-4335
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">
            €55.00
        </div>
        <div class="item-brand">
            Adidas
        </div>
        <div class="item-category">
            Shoes
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="item-name">
            <h1>Nike Yellow Sandals</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item-id">
            SKU-9654
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">
            €11.00
        </div>
        <div class="item-brand">
            Nike
        </div>
        <div class="item-category">
            Sandals
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="item-name">
            <h1>Vans Black Sneakers</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item-id">
            SKU-362364
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">
            €99.00
        </div>
        <div class="item-brand">
            Vans
        </div>
        <div class="item-category">
            Sneakers
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing right away, try putting the object into a variable first:

```
const dlObject = {
    event: 'Ecommerce - Item List Views',
    event_name: 'view_item_list',
    view_item_list: {
        items: [{
            item_name: itemName,
            item_id: itemId, 
            price: itemPrice, 
            item_brand: itemBrand,
            item_category: itemCategory, 
        }]
    }
}
```

now you can enrich it by adding more stuff into it:

```
dlObject.view_item_list.items.push({
  item_name:'second item',
  item_id:'qweqwe',price:"15", 
  item_brand:"foo", 
  item_category:"bar"
});
```

finally, once you're done pushing products to the items array, you push the whole thing in:

```
window.dataLayer.push(dlObject);
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, it sends the all the products inside the same object, it does the same as i have above

Comment: it is supposed to send all product in the same object. What are you trying to achieve?